# Thread crash when rendering out on evve blender 2.8

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, crash

```
Process:               Blender [11080]
Path:                  /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender
Identifier:            org.blenderfoundation.blender
Version:               2.81a (2.81a 2019-12-04)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Blender [11080]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-02-13 23:50:16.801 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A603)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)

Time Awake Since Boot: 16000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        27 

Total thread count: 43

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
Graphics kernel error: 0xfffffff9

Thread 27 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff7441847a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff744d5707 pthread_kill + 384
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff743a0aa2 __abort + 139
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff743a0a17 abort + 135
4   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00007fff5d90b0a6 gpusGenerateCrashLog.cold.1 + 94
5   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00007fff5d9021e7 gpusGenerateCrashLog + 89
6   com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver 0x000000011f561641 gpusKillClientExt + 9
7   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00007fff5d9035bc gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 164
8   com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver 0x000000011f53bbfa glrATI_Hwl_SubmitPacketsWithToken + 110
9   com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver 0x000000011f537b59 glrATI_Hwl_UpdateContextBufferState + 84
10  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x00007fff5d905018 gldUpdateDrawFramebuffer + 114
11  GLEngine                       0x00007fff478f4a6b gleUpdateDrawFramebufferState + 527
12  GLEngine                       0x00007fff4782fcdc glClear_Exec + 205
13  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001118f4204 EEVEE_shadows_draw_cubemap + 660
14  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001118f282f EEVEE_shadows_draw + 271
15  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001118ef2ce EEVEE_render_draw + 926
16  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001118e2cd8 eevee_render_to_image + 88
17  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001118c0e4c DRW_render_to_image + 828
18  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x000000010d886406 RE_engine_render + 1110
19  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x000000010d890c9a do_render_all_options + 378
20  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x000000010d893074 RE_RenderAnim + 2260
21  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x00000001132487f0 render_startjob + 96
22  org.blenderfoundation.blender 0x000000010da2f1e7 do_job_thread + 39
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff744d5d76 _pthread_start + 125
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff744d25d7 thread_start + 15
```

Comment: Please use Window menu > file a bug to file a bug report to Blender. Or fill out this form https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to belong to https://blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn’t that comment an answer, @ankii

Answer (score 1):

Please do these three things:

- Run this command in Terminal :

  ```
  /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender --debug-all >> ~/Downloads/eevecrash.txt
  ```

  Try to get the crash again now.
- Open blender normally again and go to Window menu > Save system Info.
- Window menu > File a bug report. Attach the files to the report made in the first two steps, plus the text you've posted here.

You should also check if the following versions cause the crash:
https://builder.blender.org/download/